# REX.W prefix on x86-64 MOV instruction with segment register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, instructions, machine-code

I am reading the [x86/x64 developer's manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) trying to understand instruction encoding and got confused by the mov from segment register, i.e. the 12th and 13th form on [this page](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov). There are two specific questions:

(1) Both are labeled with REX.W prefix, but to my understanding this flag is only used when operand size is 64 bit. I can see why it should be used with r64, but except for that, why are these two instructions labeled with REX.W prefix?

(2) There is a m16 destination in both instructions, isn't it a duplication? Why these two instructions are separated in the first place?

One reason I can think of for (2) is that in the first form, r16/r32 can be selected with 66H prefix, while 66H is ignored when REX.W exists (for r64). But the 66H doesn't seem to work for m16 either, why is that included in the second form (r64/m16)?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're talking about the case where the segment register is the destination or source operand of the MOV instruction, but the Intel manual lists both REX.W forms as having an a *r/m64* operand as the other operand, and zero extending the result when the source is segment register.  The later behaviour is different from MOV *r/m16*, *Sreg* where bits 16 through 31 of the destination register are undefined depending on the CPU model.

Comment: @RossRidge: *The upper bits of the destination register are zero for ... and **all Intel 64** processors.*  The only exceptions are 32-bit-only CPUs.  I haven't checked AMD manuals, but I think in 64-bit mode you can count on MOV from a segment register zero-extending into a full integer register.  (with no prefixes, neither REX nor `66` operand-size).  The recent [Quark X1000](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/79084/intel-quark-soc-x1000-16k-cache-400-mhz.html) they mention specifically is another 32-bit-only CPU (based on P5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that that is an editing error. I think that the REX prefix is supposed to be omitted from line 12, to contrast with the 16-bit form on line 11 and the 64-bit form on line 13 (just as there are 16- 32-, and 64-bit forms for other variants).

(Perhaps there was an attempt to combine the three forms into a single line.  The "description" column for that entry says "*Move zero extended 16-bit segment register to r16/r32/**r64**/m16*", so that's consistent with someone starting to merge the rows and then realizing that the `r64` row should be separate, but forgetting to remove the REX.W from the 16/32-bit row.)

I think the reason that m16 appears on all three forms is that **a move from a segment register into memory is always 16 bits**, regardless of the operand size.  `mov` from SR is a weird instruction.

---

There is no reason to ever use the 64-bit form: all CPUs that support 64-bit mode zero-extended to the full register size with no prefixes.

> The upper bits of the destination register are zero for ... and all Intel 64 processors.

The exceptions are 32-bit-only CPUs older than Pentium Pro, and [Quark (based on P5)](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/79084/intel-quark-soc-x1000-16k-cache-400-mhz.html) which is also 32-bit only.

I didn't check AMD manuals to see if there's a possibility that any AMD64 CPUs might leave the upper 6 bytes of RAX undefined or unmodified for `8c d8`  (`mov eax,ds` with no prefixes).  But Intel's manual is clear that all Intel64 CPUs will zero-extend to 32-bit (and thus implicitly to 64-bit like always when writing a 32-bit register).

---

The `66h` operand size prefix can be used to encode `66 8c d8` (`mov ax,ds`) which leaves the upper bytes of RAX unmodified (like always for writing a 16-bit register).

Normally you'd never want this, but the operand-size prefix *does* affect `mov reg, SR` unlike REX.W.

Comment: *since the destination is always zero-extended to the full register size*: No, I just tested on Skylake in 64-bit mode, and `66 8c d8`  ( `mov  ax,ds`  as assembled by NASM/YASM) does leave the upper bytes of RAX unmodified.  (After setting them with `or rax,-1`).  So you can use a `66` prefix to force 16-bit operand-size for the write to AX, if for some reason you want that.  In NASM, you have to write `mov eax, ds` if you want the no-prefixes version.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that it does that without a REX or operand size prefix, but I didn't say it quite right, did I?

Comment: @PeterCordes I remember the manual mentioned on 64-bit mode, only 32-bit operations will be zero-extended, while 16-bit and 8-bit will keep high bits untouched. (This also allow to use xor eax, eax to zero rax register.)

Comment: @WuZhenwei: yes, of course that's how normal instructions work ([Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](//stackoverflow.com/q/11177137)).  It would have been *possible* that `mov reg, SR` ignored `66` operand-size prefixes, so its operand-size was effectively fixed at 32/64-bit for register destinations, and 16-bit for memory.  But it turns out that's not the case, which is why PRL's answer needs an edit.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. That makes sense. Also if line 13 has REX.W, the Compat/Leg Mode should be N.E.?

Comment: @PeterCordes You're right. I think REX.W makes no difference but 66H still affects the behavior.

Comment: @WuZhenwei: Yes, I think prl's theory that it's an editing error is very likely.  Obviously the REX.W has to be optional for an encoding that can work in 32-bit mode, or it would need to be described separately.  You might want to post on Intel's forums to report this bug in their manual.  Minor bugs like this *do* happen, especially when it's pretty clear what it should be (so experienced devs just figure it out and don't stop to report it.)  And of course most people just let tools (assembler/disassembler) do the encoding/decoding for them and never notice.

Answer (score 2):

The manual has been notorious for its typos and (self)inconsistencies for decades. And it's not the only, first or last one to be sloppy. So, there shouldn't be much surprise, unless it's your first manual to read ever.

Yes, REX.W doesn't make a lot of sense with operand sizes smaller than 64 bits.

However, the REX prefix may be there (if in 64-bit mode) but with .W=0 and in this case the operand size will be 32-bit. That is, unless there's also the operand size prefix (66H), which will flip it to 16 bits.

And there may be REX.[RXB] to change the operand address encoding (to use registers r8 and beyond) without affecting the operand size.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wouldn't expect such an important manual contains so many error not fixed for so long... I feel lucky at least the basic concept part (e.g., instruction format) is quite right. Otherwise it just stops us new comers from understanding anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does. Here is the list of typos discovered by me: https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/links.htm#IntelAVX512